# Why am I getting "Undefined index" from my PHP?

Tags: php, undefined-index

When I run this code:

```
<?php
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+$/', $_GET['p'])) {
  $page = realpath("includes/$_GET[p].php");
  if ($page) {
    include $page;
  }
}
?>
```

I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: p in index.php on line 3

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 12):

The error message says that there is no array item with the key `p`. If you cannot guarantee that a variable (or array item) does exist, you should first check it with the [`isset` function](http://docs.php.net/isset):

```
if (isset($_GET['p']) && preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+$/', $_GET['p'])) {
    $page = realpath("includes/$_GET[p].php");
    if ($page) {
        include $page;
    }
}
```

Comment: in my opionion this is not a solution for the problem...

Comment: It's just wrong code because "$_GET[p]" means you access the constant "p". It works nevertheless because PHP guesses you meant the string 'p'.

Comment: @Dazmorgan: That’s not true. `$a=array('foo'=>'foo','bar'=>'bar'); define('foo', 'bar'); echo "$a[foo]"` is echoing “foo” and not “bar”. Thus it’s interpreted as `$a['foo']`.

Comment: define('p', 'bar'); outside a string in double quotes the constant will return the string bar, which will look up the index bar in the array. Its a bad habit to get into imo, but it works, for now.

Answer (score 5):

What Gumbo said for checking if the index is set in the array.

Also for [parsing an array index in a string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) you should use brackets around the array, and you should escape the index with single quotes if it is a string.

```
$page = realpath("includes/{$_GET['p']}.php");
```

But for including files suggested by the user, the safest way is to look up the files in an array, and only include them if they exists there.

Answer (score 4):

```
$page = realpath("includes/ " . $_GET['p'] . ".php");
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no real problem. PHP yields a *Notice* not a *Warning* or *Error*. Basically, your script is not receiving the `p` URL parameter. So it uses '' and gives a notice in the log. If you see this message on your rendered page, adjust php error reporting to something like `E_ERROR | E_WARNING` in PHP.ini

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'p' parameter to the page, maybe? Did you mean `$_REQUEST` instead?
Also, is it not `"${_GET['p']}" when you are accessing an array?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [array_key_exists()](http://www.php.net/array_key_exists) for checking whether an array key... exists. But in your case I suggest you pick up the [filter](http://www.php.net/filter) class of functions which specialize in working with user input.

Comment: $_GET and $_POST set by the web server will only have string or array values. array_key_exists is only needed if null is a valid value.