# PHP undefined offset or undefined index issue unresolved

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I getting “Undefined index” from my PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741750/why-am-i-getting-undefined-index-from-my-php)

```
$pattern2 = "/([A-Za-z0-9\.\-\_\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}]+)\@([A-Za-z0-9.-_]+)(\.[A-Za-z]{2,5})/";

foreach ($lines as $email) {
    preg_match($pattern2,$email,$goodies);
    $goodies[0]=filter_var($goodies[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    if(filter_var($goodies[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        array_push($good,$goodies[0]);
    }
}
```

I am pasting a bunch of data from an old flatfile in a textarea in attempt to grab out the emails.

Everything works and it pulls out the emails fine. The pattern2 is the only one I tried that was lose enough to work for me.

The problem is I am getting an undefined offset in my error log. On the line where the first `goodies[0]` appears.

I changed all of the `goodies[0]` to `goodies['0']` and I get an undefined index error.

I have tried for hours to fix this and I am at my wits end.

Thanks in advance for anyone who can fix this for me!

Comment: You should check if the regex is matching (eg: `preg_match()` returns true). It is probably just failing to match

Comment: You don't have to escape every single symbol in your character class.

Comment: I still don;t understand. Should I do an if preg_match to avoid this?

Comment: Would removing the escapes from the pattern help?

Comment: Please help this beginner, I need to recover my old address book for my band contacts data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I still don;t understand. Should I do
>   an if preg_match to avoid this?

Yes - doing that (or running isset() on the $goodies array) will be the only way to address the issue.

```
$pattern2 = "/([A-Za-z0-9\.\-\_\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}]+)\@([A-Za-z0-9.-_]+)(\.[A-Za-z]{2,5})/";

foreach ($lines as $email) {
    if( preg_match($pattern2,$email,$goodies) ) {
        $goodies[0]=filter_var($goodies[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        if(filter_var($goodies[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            array_push($good,$goodies[0]);
        }
    }
}
```